# How to turn laser scan to point cloud map

Tags: laserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm fairly new to ROS and was wondering if there was a way to convert a ".bag" laser scan file into a point cloud map. I have successfully run the "laser.bag" scan file, provided by ROS, in Rviz. Now I am curious to know how to turn this "laser.bag" file into a 3D map.

Thanks you for your time,

Tyler

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11232/how-to-turn-laser-scan-to-point-cloud-map/) by [tyler258](https://answers.ros.org/users/1092/tyler258/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2011-09-16

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One quick way to do this would be to use the [laser_geometry](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_geometry) node. It provides functionality for converting laser scans directly into PointCloud or PointCloud2 messages in the frame of your choice. That's what I use, and it's quite simple to do. I hope this helps.

**EDIT:** To use this functionality, you could do something like this:

In the class definition:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <laser_geometry/laser_geometry.h>

class My_Filter {
     public:
        My_Filter();
        void scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan);
     private:
        ros::NodeHandle node_;
        laser_geometry::LaserProjection projector_;
        tf::TransformListener tfListener_;

        ros::Publisher point_cloud_publisher_;
        ros::Subscriber scan_sub_;
};

My_Filter::My_Filter(){
        scan_sub_ = node_.subscribe<sensor_msgs::LaserScan> ("/scan", 100, &My_Filter::scanCallback, this);
        point_cloud_publisher_ = node_.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("/cloud", 100, false);
        tfListener_.setExtrapolationLimit(ros::Duration(0.1));
}
```

In the callback function:

```
void My_Filter::scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan){
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud;
    projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("base_link", *scan, cloud, tfListener_);
    point_cloud_publisher_.publish(cloud);
}
```

And the main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "my_filter");

    My_Filter filter;

    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

Where "base_link" is the frame that you'd like to see all the scans in, *scan is the reference to the incoming laser scan, cloud is the sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 that you'd like to be your output (this can also be a regular sensor_msgs::PointCloud), and tfListener_ is your transform listener.

You must also add the following to your manifest.xml:

```
<depend package="laser_geometry"/>
<depend package="tf"/>
<depend package="sensor_msgs" />
```

That's how I build my LaserScans into point clouds. I can provide a more specific example if you need it.

**EDIT**: I have updated the code snippets such that if you paste all of the code into a .cpp file, build the file, and run it, it will work 100%. You should change "/scan" to the topic that your laser publishes, and you should change "/cloud" to the topic you wish to view the cloud on. In Rviz, add a new PointCloud2 visualizer and point it to the topic you chose for "/cloud" and it should work. This node also assumes that there is a tf from the frame of the laser to the target frame ("base_link" in this example).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 21

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2011-12-05**:
How a tf from based_laser to based_link can be achieved?

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-09-26**:
Just some advice, I wouldn't rename "/cloud" to "/base_link" because that could get confusing. You want "/cloud" to be the name of data stream, not the frame that it's in. To see it in Rviz, add a new PointCloud2 and link it to "/cloud" or whatever you've named it.

**Comment by [tyler258](https://answers.ros.org/users/1092/tyler258/) on 2011-09-26**:
Okay, I got the code running but I'm still having trouble publishing it in Rviz. The laser scan data I have publishes to tilt_scan. So I replaced "/scan" with "/tilt_scan" and I replaced "/cloud" with "/base_link" but this is still not working.  Also, how do I get access to this new map?

**Comment by [tyler258](https://answers.ros.org/users/1092/tyler258/) on 2011-09-23**:
Would you mind providing the more specific example I would appreciate it. Right now I have my .cpp file set up, more or less, just like the example you provided. Now once I run the .cpp file, I run "rosbag play my_laser_data.bag" but I can't anything to show up in rviz.

**Comment by [tyler258](https://answers.ros.org/users/1092/tyler258/) on 2011-09-21**:
Could you explain how to call the transformLaserScanToPointCloud() function in the laser_gemoetry class?

**Comment by [AG1617](https://answers.ros.org/users/4890/ag1617/) on 2013-05-14**:
Running 12.04 and groovy, the following error comes up: /opt/ros/groovy/include/laser_geometry/laser_geometry.h:46:22: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory

Any help?

**Comment by [Bernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4949/bernhard/) on 2013-06-05**:
I had the same problem as you AG1617, you'll have to edit the file manually and fill in the correct path, usually the file is somewhere here /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/core

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2014-07-20**:
what is the difference between the target frame and frame id ?? the frame id for the /scan topic in my case is laser0_frame. So should it be the target frame or not ?

**Comment by [Mudassir Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4582/mudassir-khan/) on 2014-07-31**:
for /opt/ros/groovy/include/laser_geometry/laser_geometry.h:46:22: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory try http://answers.ros.org/question/185948/eigencore-on-ros-hydro/

**Comment by [Tooght](https://answers.ros.org/users/28665/tooght/) on 2016-11-30**:
Hi .I followed the above steps but it didn't work.
CMakeFiles/My_Filter.dir/src/My_Filter.cpp.o: In function `My_Filter::My_Filter()': My_Filter.cpp:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to` tf::Transformer::DEFAULT_CACHE_TIME'
My_Filter.cpp:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `tf::Transformer::DEFAULT

**Comment by [lounis](https://answers.ros.org/users/33728/lounis/) on 2018-02-21**:
Hi D. I came here as I want convert laserscans into pointcloud2. I've laserScans stored in a bag. I tried ur code. The error I get is with the difference in timestamps between laserscans, the bag (generated later on) and current time (tf's). I tried wth sim time but didnt work. Any help is wlcm.10x

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Using Python to do the conversion simplifies a lot. Let's see how to do that using the `laser_geometry` package.

First, you need to launch the `laser_geometry` package from a launch file, properly configured. Here a suggested launch file:

```
<launch>
<node type="laser_scan_assembler" pkg="laser_assembler"
    name="my_assembler">
<remap from="scan" to="laser_scan"/>
<param name="max_scans" type="int" value="400" />
<param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="my_robot_link_base" />
 </node>
  <node type ="laser2pc.py" pkg="laser_to_pcl" name="laser2pc"/>
</launch>
```

That file launches the `laser_geometry` package indicating that the frame from which the transform will be done is the `my_robot_link_base` (that is whatever tf link of your robot you want the point cloud to be refered from). Another parameter is the `max_scans` which indicates the max number of last scans that will be take into account for the computation of the point cloud ( this is useful in case your laser is rotating, so you can generate a full 3D cloud).

The launch file above also launches a second node that is the one you have to create to get the data and publish it into your selected topic. What should be the code of such a node? Check the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy 
from laser_assembler.srv import AssembleScans2
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2

rospy.init_node("assemble_scans_to_cloud")
rospy.wait_for_service("assemble_scans2")
assemble_scans = rospy.ServiceProxy('assemble_scans2', AssembleScans2)
pub = rospy.Publisher ("/laser_pointcloud", PointCloud2, queue_size=1)

r = rospy.Rate (1)

while (True):
    try:
        resp = assemble_scans(rospy.Time(0,0), rospy.get_rostime())
        print "Got cloud with %u points" % len(resp.cloud.data)
        pub.publish (resp.cloud)

    except rospy.ServiceException, e:
        print "Service call failed: %s"%e

    r.sleep()
```

The code shows how to subscribe to the `assemble_scans2` service. That is the one that will provide the point cloud on its answer. The code also shows that the point cloud will be published on a topic of type `PoinCloud2`. basically, the while loop what it does is, first, call to the service, then publish the answer of the service into a topic.

I have created a video (https://youtu.be/GvilxcePD64) showing how to use the laser_geometry with Python with a practical example.

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) with karma: 874 on 2017-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-24**:
As always with videos, please add a short description describing the main points / steps to your answer. If your video ever disappears, your answer becomes useless.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-02**:
This glosses over the meat of the question: how to turn a laser scan into a point cloud. Instead, you still direct people to look at your video. @DimitriProsser's answer is much more detailed and actually *answers the question*.

**Comment by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) on 2017-10-03**:
Thanks @jayess for stating what already was stated in the previous comment.
As you can see in [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/271978/error-while-launching-robot-model/#272100) I learnt the lesson, so no need to keep pushing. Use that time instead to answer yourself the question

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-03**:
@R. Tellez: I'm commenting on the current version of this answer which was updated since the first comment. So, even if you have started giving more info on other answers *this answer* still glosses over relevant information and makes the user watch a video instead of getting an answer.

**Comment by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) on 2017-10-09**:
Modified to include everything